# How to add mysql JDBC driver to Eclipse so it can be used by SQL Explorer?

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jdbc

I would like where am I supposed to install MySQL JDBC driver in Eclipse so it can be detected and used by SQL Explorer.

Just to be clear, if possible, I would like to copy the [MySQL J connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) to somewhere inside Eclipse. Also a solution with an Eclipse install repository would also be good.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Check this [Driver Preferences](http://www.sqlexplorer.org/drivers.php)

Comment: Can the path be relative, so I can obtain a portable Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

you can use this tutorial :
http://www.od2dev.be/configuring-aptana-to-connect-mysql-databases/

and it work even without the part of changing the port used by mysql

Comment: On SO, when providing a link to an external site, it is often best to give at least a high level summary of what the contents are in case the external link changes or is deleted. Future SO visitors will still have *something* to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Just click the Edit button, and specify the correct location of the jar.